# Image Loading From a Folder After JAR Conversion

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

In my project i have to load images stored in a folder in source folder. But after i convert the project into jar it cant load any images.( I have selected the image(sticker) folder as resource when jar conversion and found many similar question in stackoverflow but they dont work for me).As i have to work in Intellij IDE so it will be good if you say for Intellij(14).
Code for loading image

```
void load()
{
    sticker[0]="sticker\\bang.gif";
    sticker[1]="sticker\\birthday.gif";
    sticker[2]="sticker\\bye.gif";
    sticker[3]="sticker\\cry.gif";
    sticker[4]="sticker\\dance.gif";
    sticker[5]="sticker\\exercise.gif";
    sticker[6]="sticker\\headbang.gif";
    sticker[7]="sticker\\jail.gif";
    sticker[8]="sticker\\killing.gif";
    sticker[9]="sticker\\kiss.gif";
    sticker[10]="sticker\\laugh.gif";
    sticker[11]="sticker\\leftright.gif";
    sticker[12]="sticker\\light.gif";
    sticker[13]="sticker\\listening.gif"
}
```

[image: projectStructure]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a class loader to load resources that are packaged in the jar itself.

```
public class FooClass {

    public void load(){

        InputStream sticker = FooClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/to/sticker.gif");

    }

}
```